# Error: sync: Channel 'enterprise' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.14

When trying to sync installed modules I get the following error: `Error:
sync: Channel 'enterprise' doesn't exist`

When I try to remove the channel I get: `Error:
channel-delete: 'enterprise' was not found in aliases, channel names, channel uris`

Comment: is this when using `./mage`?

Comment: Yes, it is using `./mage`

Answer (score 1):

At least in CE this can be overcome by running `./mage mage-setup` on the command line. Worth a try.

Running `./mage clear-cache` prior to setup may be necessary in order to reset local channel info.

Comment: `./mage mage-setup` returns the same error - "`Error: sync: Channel 'enterprise' doesn't exist`"

Comment: Answer updated, hope that helps. Still only _educated guess_ as I cannot reproduce the error locally.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. I cleared the cache, ran setup and then ran sync and.. `Successfully added: community/BL_CustomGrid-0.8.9
Successfully added: community/Bronto_Extension-2.4.2.2
Error:
sync: Channel 'enterprise' doesn't exist`